# javascript substitute DOM element

Tags: javascript, html, dom

I would like to do something like:

```
var htmlcode = '<div>testing</div>';
document.getElementById('initDiv').html = htmlcode;
```

kinda like using innerHTML but replacing the element itself.

Can someone help me please?
thanks

Comment: Replacing **what** element? What's your html mark-up?

Comment: my question is very simple. but my html markup would be     
<div id="initDiv">blablabla</div>            
please don't tell me i can use innerHTML because i know i could, that is not my question. thanks

Comment: Do you *need* to create the element *inside* of the `htmlcode` variable? Or would you be willing to use `document.createElement()`?

Comment: I would rather do:  var htmlcode = '<div>testing</div>'; parent.createElement(htmlcode); parent.removeElement(original); - something like that

Answer (score 4, accepted):

No, there's no native cross-browser solution to your problem. The best you could do would be to piece together something that will work in a more cross-browser manner.

Here's one solution:

```
function outerHTML( el, html ) {
    if ( 'outerHTML' in el ) {   // for most browsers
        el.outerHTML = html;
    } else {                     // for Firefox
        var temp = document.createElement('div');
        temp.innerHTML = html;
        while (temp.firstChild) {
            el.parentNode.insertBefore( temp.firstChild, el );
        }
        el.parentNode.removeChild(el);
    }
};
```

Use it like this:

```
var initDiv = document.getElementById('initDiv');

outerHTML( initDiv, '<div>testing</div>' );
```

**Example:** http://jsfiddle.net/6VUNU/1/

Answer (score 1):

There is a `document.getElementById(...).outerHTML` value that you can use, but as far as I remember it's not usable in all browsers.

Answer (score 1):

You can always find initDiv's parent, createElement('div'), populate it with htmlcode, and then removeElement on the initDiv.

Comment: that's a good idea, but i would think there would be something focused on this...

Comment: Once the node is gone, it's gone. If it's simply a div you can just change out the innerHTML and it will appear as a new div to the user. If you're getting complicated with DOM manipulation for a game or something, you might want to check out jQuery as it makes all these actions very simple and cross-browser friendly.

Comment: i appreciate it, but this is for a very specific academic project, i can't use any external libraries. @patrick dw's answer really suits my needs...